# Wordpress Video Align middle not working

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a problem with one WordPress theme.

This is [URL](http://www.socialextensions.com) of my site and if you scroll down to the `iFB` section
then you will see a video there.

I have entered this code to put it to this page

```
<iframe 
     src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KO2hFoKDh18" 
     width="560" 
     height="315" 
     frameborder="0" 
     align="middle" 
     allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
></iframe>
```

but still going left.

Anyone that can help me?

Comment: try adding `display:block; margin: 0 auto` to the styling of the iframe ... this should center the video on the page.

Comment: @Aravona thats the problem i dont know where is the styling of this part. and the developer of the theme is not answering to emails.
could you login with a temp admin pass and find it out please?

Comment: I'd rather not - is this your only iframe? if it's WP then try the Page itself in the admin, the single.php, page.php, index.php pages and see if it's listed there - it should be as it's your home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KO2hFoKDh18" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>


  element.style {
                  margin-left: 400px;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to align your data than you can align it many ways. align center was not working do you to inheritance so you could it with css. make a class here style. so in script tag you can give margin-left so it will move towards right adjust as you need.

```
 .style {
              margin-left: 400px;
            }
</style>
   <iframe class="style" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/KO2hFoKDh18"   width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer a little?

Comment: dude i have taken a class name style. within a script tag you can write .style and the property that is margin-left. as simple as that.

Comment: I am not asking to explain what you did, but why it works.  These answers are not just for the person asking the question but for future people who also have this same question and get here somehow.   A little bit of text explaining why doing x gives you y is normally appreciated.

Comment: is it ok @NathanOliver.